# i2c_hid i2c-ite33d1:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4) on Arch Linux Boot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot

I just installed Arch Linux on my Laptop (Lenovo Y720 Gaming laptop). 9/10 times I boot the drive it just spams me with:

> i2c_hid i2c-ite33d1:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (2/4)

(Attached in the image below).

It outputs like a couple hundred thousand of these messages infinitely and I can't access the system for further installation/configuration.

People reported a similar problem with some ELAN device, but I don't have that (or I'm not aware of it). I found that there was a fix for this in the kernel 2 years ago but I can't seem to bypass it.

EDIT: The fix was committed [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ef6eaf27274c0351f7059163918f3795da13199c), but it's somewhat not for the same error.

[image]

Comment: Try blacklisting the module that's causing this. I assume by "you can't access the system" you mean "the error messages get in the way, so I can't type"? If yes, (a) try a different VT (CTRL-ALT-F2 etc.), or try to `ssh` in from another computer. Then do an `lsmod`, or look at syslog/`dmesg` to identify the module that's causing it.

Comment: this seems to be a common issue with touchpads on Asus laptops.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same bugs with y720, and solved it as follows:

1. `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. exchange this line :
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`
3. `sudo update-grub`
4. `reboot`

Comment: Did you do this from the Live USB or were you able to boot in the system?

Comment: in my case , it seems to be a problem with the touchpad . the system boot right, and cpu  came down。

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by unloading/blacklisting the **i2c_hid** kernel module. I have not observed any loss of functionality after doing that (keyboard and touchpad still work).

I have found that [a patch](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-input/20191127032329.8406-1-admin@kryma.net/) was very recently added to the kernel which silences these kernel messages. I have tested it but found that while it does fix the messages, there is still high CPU usage (about 25% of one core) due to the interrupt firing all the time. Unloading the kernel module stopped this.